# java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration

Tags: java, security, config

I deployed an application in Tomcat and when tried to log in, it threw this error.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration

    com.sun.security.auth.login.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:93)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$3.run(Configuration.java:247)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:242)
    javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$1.run(LoginContext.java:237)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:234)
    javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:403)
    com.cognizant.dcipher.server.actions.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:57)
    com.cognizant.dcipher.server.actions.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:132)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

I have set `login.config.url.1=file:C:/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/webapps/Dcipher/WEB-INF/classes/jaas.config` in the `java.security` file in the JDK.

Can someone please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to reference the file as a URL, perhaps you should try file:/C:/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/webapps/Dcipher/WEB-INF/classes/jaas.config (note the slash after file:)

Comment: when i run the same application in EClipse IDE i am getting a different exception:

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: FileAppender
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)